# Get all data faster from IBM Cognos Analytics database

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, analytics, cognos

I'm using IBM Cognos Analytics 11.1.7. There is a ControlHost that we can integrate JavaScript code so I'm adding codes below, it reads data from the database. it is fine to read and write data to list for 10-20 rows but when rows are getting more for example we try for 700.000 rows but it takes 30-40 minutes to read and write the rows. We tried it on the database, it takes 3 seconds to get the all data but in Cognos analytics java script code takes too much. Can we optimize the performance for this problem. Thank in advance

JavaScript code below;

```js
define(["https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"], function(d3) {
  "use strict";

  function D3BarChart() {};

  D3BarChart.prototype.draw = function(oControlHost) {
    var o = oControlHost.configuration;
    var iWidth = (o && o.Width) ? o.Width : 500;
    var iHeight = (o && o.Height) ? o.Height : 16;
    var sBackgroundColor = (o && o["Background color"]) ? o["Background color"] : "#C8F08F";

    var fnScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(this.m_aData)])
      .range([0, iWidth]);

    d3.select(oControlHost.container)
      .selectAll("div")
      .data(this.m_aData)
      .enter().append("div")
      .style("width", function(d) {
        return fnScale(d) + "px";
      })
      .style("background-color", sBackgroundColor)
      .style("border", "1px solid gray")
      .style("margin", "4px 0px 4px 0px")
      .style("height", iHeight + "px")
      .style("line-height", iHeight + "px")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d;
      });
  };

  D3BarChart.prototype.setData = function(oControlHost, oDataStore) {
    this.m_oDataStore = oDataStore;
    this.m_aData = [];
    var iRowCount = oDataStore.rowCount;
    for (var iRow = 0; iRow < iRowCount; iRow++) {
      this.m_aData.push(oDataStore.getCellValue(iRow, 1));
    }
  };

  return D3BarChart;
});
```

Comment: I don't see any logging calls in the custom control.  Add logging to determine where the slowdown is.  For example, is the draw() method slow or is the setData() method slow?  Also, turn on the performance tracking tools in the report authoring tool, run it a few times, and post the results.

Comment: Also, what about the report structure?  Where is the custom control?  Being a bar chart, I would assume it is just on the page and not in another viz.  But I don't like to assume.  If it's in a list, you're processing 700k rows for every row in your list.

Comment: How are `sql` or `node.js` related to this question?